# Passing value from one component to another in react for updating the login status to navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend

``i want to pass the status of islogged from login.js file to navbar file to update the name as per the user logined . `Can anyone please cehck and help me out in this .Passing value from one component to another in react for updating the login status to navbar`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeMF6.png)```

Comment: export const Navbar = (props) => {
  console.log(props.isLoggedIn)
  const products=useSelector((state)=>state.cart.cartItems)
  // console.log(products.length)
    {props.isLoggedIn==="true"?<Link to="/"  className='mx-4 font-extrabold text-xl hover:text-green-600'>{localStorage.getItem("name")}</Link>: null}